# Symfony Compiler Pass - do i need to implement priority or it is already implemented

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Symfony version: 3.4

I am wondering if I need to implement priority attribute myself in compiler pass or it is already implemented?

Mainly I am trying to register service provider for an external library "scheb/two-factor-bundle" to be loaded before its provider.
[Compiler pass in question.](https://github.com/scheb/two-factor-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ProviderCompilerPass.php)

I am trying to use priority attribute on a tag but it seems not to be working.

Is priority something Symfony takes in consideration when calling for `findTaggedServiceIds` in `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder`

**UPDATE**
As is noted by [@fabian-papet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1617144/fabien-papet) this is left for implementation to a developer.
Don't fear symfony was helpful in this case also. I have found a [trait](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/8de4311a5b58978a74492fd3ee00451c9ced727c/Compiler/PriorityTaggedServiceTrait.php) that can help in this case `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\CompilerPriorityTaggedServiceTrait`. 
All thanks to the author Iltar van der Berg.

Answer (score 0):

The is no such a feature integrated in Symfony to add priority to tags. This is a feature you'll have to implement.
Here's a summary of the `findTaggedServiceIds` function:

```
<?php
function findTaggedServiceIds($name, $throwOnAbstract = false)
{
    $this->usedTags[] = $name;
    $tags = array();
    foreach ($this->getDefinitions() as $id => $definition) {
        if ($definition->hasTag($name)) {
            $tags[$id] = $definition->getTag($name);
        }
    }
}
```